# Are there specific names for forehead jewelry?

Tags: image-identification

I googled "forehead jewelry" and found a lot of them in google photos, but I'm looking a specific name for this type of jewelry that falls on the forehead (and couldn't find there one).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circlet
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diadem

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean [Maangtika and Jhoomar](https://www.indianfusion.co.za/traditional-indian-jewellery-types-names-and-origins/).

There are a few other variations you can find [here](https://mymarriagewebsite.com/indian-wedding-jewelry-and-indian-bridal-jewellery/).

Comment: The photos OP posted are not of an english item...

Comment: What has that got to do with anything? There doesn't have to be an English translation for every word. I bet if I asked any of my Indian friends what those words mean in English, they would give me a discription, not a single word. Since it's not a common piece of Jewellery for an English speaking person to wear, it's unlikely to get it's own English word. Note, that the French translation of selfie, is still selfie. Many words are never directly translated since they are already commonplace in multiple cultures.

Comment: I thought s/he was looking for an English term. I guess I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any generic English term for this type of jewelry. Such jewelry is not a common element of any English-speaking culture's fashion.

The items in your photos appear to be [maang tika](https://www.indianfusion.co.za/traditional-indian-jewellery-types-names-and-origins/), but this is not an English name and chances are not a name that most English speakers will be familiar with.

Comment: Many Indians speak English.

Comment: @Lambie Quite true, but it is an adopted language, and the linguistic origin of the culture from which these items originate is not English, nor are the names.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers suggest, you can use the common Indian names for these jewelry -- but you might have to describe them for those who don't know what you mean.  You could call these a kind of "jeweled headband", although "tiara" might also work:

> **[tiara](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tiara)** (n):  A jeweled ornamental band worn on the front of a woman's hair.

Most "tiaras" look very different from these Indian styles, as they are more like *crowns*, and very ornate:

[image] [image]

A "tiara" can have a simple design, such as those worn by brides:

[image] [image]

There is no distinct line between "headband" and "tiara", for example this item marketed as an "amethyst tiara / simple amethyst headband":

[image]

As you might expect, "tiara" sounds much fancier than "headband".

(Edit) I found many hundreds of items from a google search on "forehead tiara".  Here are seven images from this very long list:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: tiaras are not placed around the forehead.

Comment: @Lambie  Did you even bother to check, or are you just objecting without evidence?  I've updated the answer with seven images out of countless hundreds from a Google search.   Your downvote is entirely unwarranted, and I wish you would please stop.

Comment: @Andrew although I agree Lambie is being a bit harsh on all the proposed answers for this question and that tiara is a good suggestion. I have to agree that tiaras aren't *commonly* placed around the forehead. As your google search showed, you'd need to specify the type

Comment: @Bee  The meaning of any word in a language is based, ultimately, on how it is used.  "Tiara" may traditionally refer to a kind of crown, but nevertheless it is also used to describe jewelry worn on the forehead.  I would have said that the images in OP's question are a *kind of* tiara.   In any case a downvote should be based on *facts*, not opinions.  In this case it would have been trivial to check.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not arguing with that, I'm just saying that if you said tiara, I would think of one worn by a princess as in your first two pictures and I thought that was worth mentioning to the OP.

Comment: @Bee  I know, I know.  I apologize.  It's just irritating to be downvoted after I've make considerable effort to substantiate my answer, by those who seem to rely instead on personal instinct.

Comment: I don't think that Lambie has actually even provided an answer. These things happen though. I've been down voted when I think I've provided more concise and well referenced answers than other people before!